# Регулярное выражение для поиска доменного имени, как правильно составить?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как правильно составить регулярное выражение?
Здравствуйте.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как составить регулярку. Есть строка `http://РАНДОМНЫЙ-ДОМЕН/`, требуется найти `РАНДОМНЫЙ-ДОМЕН` (т.е. название и длина может быть произвольное, так же могут присутствовать допустимые символы: `-`, `_`, `.`) и заменить, для примера, на `localhost`.

Чего-то не могу сообразить, как выбрать между `//` ... `/`

UPD: накидал примерно такую `[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}`, но есть загвоздка. Он неправильно обрабатывает http://localhost/ (такой вариант тоже может прилететь), как можно пофиксить?

Comment: если вам надо выбрать между `//` и `/` то и выбирайте все что между ними, не нужны там никакие правила `~//(.*?)/~`

Comment: действительно, вы правы. А то я полез в дебри. Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Не подскажите один момент, при таком правиле он затирает `//` ... `/`, а они должны остаться. Не подскажите как подкорректировать регулярку?

Comment: внутрь скобок их перенесите. либо из `$matches[0]` возьмите данные, а не `[1]`

Comment: @yaleksandr89 https://qna.habr.com/q/789365

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам нужно именно ВСЕ между `//` и `/`. Это зависит от того, откуда вы это получаете. Не забывайте, что в url между этими знаками может быть так же: имя пользователя, пароль, порт. Например в случае `http://user:pass@localhost:80/abc//XYZ/?x=//!!/` что вы должны найти (обратите внимание, двойная косая может быть и далее строке в url, в разном качестве)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте регулярки там где это можно не делать. Вам, по сути, нужно парсить URL. Для этого есть функция `parse_url()`. Эта функция "знает" где должен находиться хост и какие символы там могут быть. Она сможет парсить и `http://localhost/` и `http://user:pass@host.of.the-corporation.media:80/abc//XYZ/?x=//!!/#section2`

См. [Функция parse_url()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php)